# Laravel 5 do not get updated data from mysql db

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have a problem with my Laravel project. I still work on the projet locally and with the debug mode on.

When I update my database, it gets updated. But when I want to retrieve the updated content, it still gets the old one. If I then open the project in another browser, it gets the new data. Is there some kind of browser caching of data i'm forgetting?

Regards Andreas

Comment: There is not, you should show what exactly you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I saved the team object in session, and when I used it from the session, it took the saved session data - ofcourse!